# HTML Canvas Won't Draw

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, html5-canvas

I'm trying to learn the HTML canvas, but nothing is drawing on my canvas element. What would
be the best way to proceed from here? (complete canvas beginner)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" class="center"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
let cx = document.querySelector("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

window.onload = function drawOnCanvas() {
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.moveTo(50, 10);
  cx.lineTo(10, 70);
  cx.lineTo(90, 70);
  cx.fill();
};
```

Comment: You're selecting the canvas element incorrect. You're using ```document.querySelector("myCanvas")``` which is incorrect because ```querySelector``` expects a CSS selector, and you're missing the ```#``` symbol which is used to select elements by their ```ID```. The correct way to select the canvas would be ```document.querySelector("#myCanvas")```. Then, the ```window.onload``` function is not being called because it's not defined correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myCanvas` is id of element.
document.querySelector expects a css selector.
So if you want to select element with id, you have to use prefix `#`

-javascript

```
let cx = document.querySelector("#myCanvas").getContext("2d");
```